# Token for contribution.note field in message templates

Tags: civimail, tokens, smarty

I have reviewed past posts on this topic, but I'm not a coder so I'm hoping someone can make this straight forward for me.  I.e. what code do I need to use, where do I put that code, etc.

We'd like to use the contribution note field and include it in the email notification being sent to the person the donation is in honor of (so the donor can add a custom message to the honoree).

Thanks!

Comment: How are you sending the email notification to the honoree? Is this a message template you are sending manually?

Comment: @LarsSG Yes it is a message template that is being sent through a CiviRule (i.e. when a contribution with soft credit type "in honor" is added, send the email)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using the Fuzion tokens for latest contribution here (like `{latestcontribs.something}`), which doesn't include contribution note. I think you'd have to add it to Fuzion Tokens or hire someone to do that.

Comment: Even if you're not using latestcontribs, I suspect this won't be possible without adding some code as notes aren't stored in the same way as other contribution details.